# Vue / JS Directive Event Llisterner Abstraction

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Is there any issue or a best practice to abstracting Vue event listening functionality outside of a directive as per the example below? I have two directives scroll and resize. Seems to work but scroll seems a little static at times. Seems smoother if I duplicate function `addListerner ()` code in each directive.

```
<template>
    <header v-scroll="handleScroll" v-resize="handleResize"
            class="fixed flex w-full justify-center">
<!--        Remove rest for brevity sake-->
    </header>
</template>

<script>

    function addListener(key,el, binding, vnode) {
        let f = function (evt) {
            if (binding.value(evt, el)) {
                window.removeEventListener(key, f);
            }
        };
        window.addEventListener(key, _.throttle(f, 100), {capture: false, passive: true});
    }

    export default {
        name: "Navigation",
        directives: {
            scroll: {
                inserted: function (el, binding, vnode) {
                    addListener('scroll',el, binding, vnode);
                }
            },
            resize: {
                inserted: function (el, binding, vnode) {
                    addListener('resize',el, binding, vnode);
                }
            },
        },
        computed : {
            hasActive : function() {
                return !_.isEmpty(this.active);
            }
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                active: {},
                scroll : {
                    last: 0,
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            closeMenus() {
                this.active = {};
            },
            handleScroll(evt, el) {
                if(Math.abs(this.scroll.last - window.scrollY) <= 35) return;
                this.closeMenus();

                (window.scrollY < this.scroll.last)
                    ? el.style.top = "0"
                    : el.style.top = "-" + el.clientHeight + "px";
                this.scroll.last = window.scrollY;
            },
            handleResize(evt, el) {
                this.closeMenus();
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like your `removeEventListener` will work. You're passing it `f` but that isn't the same function you passed to `addEventListener`. You'd need to retain a reference to the function returned by `throttle` instead. The developer tools in your browser should allow you to see exactly what listeners are registered where. It might be that the smoothness difference you perceive is actually caused by multiple listener fighting with each other. You should also look into ensuring proper teardown in `unbind` so that these listeners can't leak.